# Mudar background image sem fade

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, num site que estou criando tem esta imagem como "background image" numa div.

[image: Foto do predio]

Estou querendo fazer com que algumas janelas dos prédios ficam piscando, pra ter um efeito legal, uma animação nos prédios. 
Para isto, eu fiz no CSS:

```
#divprediocima {
background-image: url("../img/prediocima.png");
width: 972px;
height: 276px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -40px;
animation-name: prediocima;
animation-duration: 20s;
animation-delay: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes prediocima {
0%   {background-image: url("../img/prediocima.png");}
30%  {background-image: url("../img/prediocima1.png");}
70%  {background-image: url("../img/prediocima2.png");}
90% {background-image: url("../img/prediocima.png");}
100% {background-image: url("../img/fundo.png");}
}
```

Como tenho esta foto em vetor, fui tirando algumas janelas e salvando como outras fotos png, ou seja, tenho 3 arquivos png alguns com mais janelas e outros menos janelas.

Acontece que, está mudando o background com um efeito fade out, aí quando vai mudar de background, a janela vai sumindo aos poucos, ficando clarinho como até a foto mostra em algumas janelas... Isto não tá ficando legal.

**Como faço para o background image mudar sem ter efeito algum? Alguém sabe?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar esta técnica:

```
@keyframes prediocima {

0%   {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
30%   {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
30.01%  {background-image: url("prediocima1.png");}

70%  {background-image: url("prediocima1.png");}
70.01%  {background-image: url("prediocima2.png");}

90% {background-image: url("prediocima2.png");}
90.01% {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}

99.99% {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
100% {background-image: url("fundo.png");}

}
```

Mas diminua o tempo em `animation-duration: 20s;` para algo em torno de `5s`.

Veja o efeito funcionando abaixo com cores em lugar das imagens (só como exemplo):

```css
#divprediocima {
background: blue;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -40px;
animation-name: prediocima;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-delay: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes prediocima {
/*
0%   {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
30%   {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
30.01%  {background-image: url("prediocima1.png");}

70%  {background-image: url("prediocima1.png");}
70.01%  {background-image: url("prediocima2.png");}

90% {background-image: url("prediocima2.png");}
90.01% {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}

99.99% {background-image: url("prediocima.png");}
100% {background-image: url("fundo.png");}
*/

0%   {background: blue;}
30%   {background: blue;}
30.01%  {background: yellow;}

70%  {background: yellow;}
70.01%  {background: red;}

90% {background: red;}
90.01% {background: blue;}

99.99% {background: blue;}
100% {background: gray;}

}
```

```html
<div id="divprediocima">
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!